# MacBook with 10.4.11 2GHz Intel Core 2 Duo 1GB 667Mhz DDR2...... HELP!

Tags: macbook-pro

I am afraid I am not a Mac user so please forgive me for not knowing what I am doing.
I work with a charity which has been collecting old laptops to send to schools in Ghana, Africa. All but one have been Windows computers.
As you can see in the title of this thread I have a old Mac in my hands (in fact it looks like new!).
I have, with the help of Apple had it de-registered.
So I now have a computer with old Safari on which doesn't want to do a few things. It will not update Safari. The OS will not update. Apple said they no longer support it. So I thought I would download a different browser. Nope. No luck. I downloaded chrome but that won't install.

Does anyone know if I can make this computer worth sending to Ghana or should I bin it! I have equally old Windows computers which are now running Linux beautifully but because I don't normally use Mac I don't really understand the language used for installing on a Mac.....it is definitely not as simple!

If anyone lives in the Wigan area of the UK and want's to have a bash at putting Linux on just for the fun of it (with a working camera, touch pad, bluetooth and wifi...the CD drive is not so important) and knowing that you achieved something for a good cause I would be happy to drop it off!

Comment: This guide may help: http://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/

Comment: Can you give more information on this computer? The operating system isn't helpful as it doesn't tell us anything about the hardware, only software. What model is this laptop? What year was it made? We need to know if it's a PowerPC or Intel Macbook. If it's a PowerPC you'll need to install the PowerPC architecture version of whatever software you want. If it's Intel, you'll need to install the Intel version of the software you want. Because Apple switched architectures in 2006, you may have a harder time finding the correct software for it -- but that doesn't mean that it's "useless". It's st

Comment: I'm guessing you can boot the Mac. Go to the Apple Menu (at top left) and select About This Mac. On the window that appears, click on the More Info button. This will bring up the hardware overview screen. Take a note of the Model Identifier and post it back here. This will give us a lot more info in order to be able to help you.